# Changing the email address linked to my Steam account

Tags: steam

I found myself in kind of a big problem today as I tried logging on Steam on another computer.

The usual verification code popped up -- no problem -- the thing is that I only have access to the email address linked to my steam account from my own PC at home (I am currently using a yahoo mail address and intend to change to a gmail address).

Is there a way to change the email address that my Steam account is linked to?

Comment: I hope that you cannot change your email without logging in...

Answer (score 34):

You can change your contact email address via the steam client. Menubar -> Steam -> Settings -> Change Contact Email Address.

For security reasons you will need to log in to steam and have access to the old email address.

[image: Red freehand circles to show the button.]

Comment: Just a heads up: IIRC you won't be able to use Steam trading and the marketplace for a few days after changing your email.

Answer (score 1):

You can only change your Steam email account while logged in.

However, it is possible to access Yahoo mail from any computer using the web interface at https://mail.yahoo.com/. I hope you remember your Yahoo mail password!